# Calculate total time based on according to ID

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have a table called `DAILYDATAWH` which has a column `OID(Primary Key),ID,NAME,DEPARTMENT,WORKINGHOUR`. I want to calculate the total of the `WORKINGHOUR` column according to `ID` and save the value of total `WORKINGHOUR` in table `SUMMARYDATA` in column `TOTALWH`

This is my table `DAILYDATAWH`

[image: TABLE DAILYDATAWH]

This is my code to display table`DAILYDATAWH` :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptrDAILYDATAWH" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>NAME</th>
                                <th>DEPARTMENT</th>
                                <th>WORKINGHOUR</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <th><%# Eval("NIP") %></th>
                        <td><%# Eval("NAME") %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("DEPARTMENT") %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("WORKINGHOUR") %></td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

This is my code on backend :

```
 protected void BindDAILYDATWHARptr()
        {

            String CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MANHOURConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM DAILYDATAWH", con))
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        DataTable dtDaily = new DataTable();
                        sda.Fill(dtDaily);

                        rptrDAILYDATAWH.DataSource = dtDaily;
                        rptrDAILYDATAWH.DataBind();

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Is it possible to save that value in other table? And how to do calculate total time according to `ID` and save the value in other table?

Comment: Use `.GroupBy(id)` and `sum(WORKINGHOUR)`

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar can you write an example code how to do that? and how to save the value in other table?

Comment: do you want to show unique rows (by id) with column `TOTALWH` ?or do you want same rows with additional column `TOTALWH`?

Comment: i want same rows with additional column `TOTALWH`

Comment: @DeaAnanda , pls see if my answer helps.

Comment: @Grace Thankyou for helping me, i've try that but appear error in `ID`, it's says : `'DataRow' does not contain a definition for 'ID'`

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar i want same rows with additional column `TOTALWH`

Answer (score 0):

You can also look into this code if it helps you. It was written on MySQL Language.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SummaryData LIKE Dailydatawh;
Insert into SummaryData
Select W.* from (
Select Q.ID,Q.Name,Q.Department, Sec_to_time(Q.WorkingHour) as TotalWorkingHW from 
(Select ID,Name,Department, sum(time_to_sec(WorkingHour)) WorkingHour from Dailydatawh
group by ID)Q)W
```

Hope you will find this helpful.

Comment: Thank you for helping me, i've try that in SQL Server 2008 and convert function sec_to_time in sql server language, but it doesn't work

Comment: To get output according to requirement in SQL Server then the code will completely is different one. If you wish i can write again in SQL Server Language.

Comment: Please write again in SQL Server Language so i can try it, thankyouu